# Why does a function declaration override non-writable properties of the global object?

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables, ecmascript-5, propertydescriptor

Setting a property descriptor like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'someFunction', {
    value: function() { alert('safe'); },
    writable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false
});
```

...should, as far as I know, make the `someFunction` property of `window` non-writable. It works for *function expressions* as I expect, whether the function is directly assigned to the object property... <sup>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QqrBj/1/)</sup>

```
window.someFunction = function() { alert('boom!'); }
someFunction(); // safe
```

...or assigned to a global variable: <sup>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QqrBj/)</sup>

```
var someFunction = function() { alert('boom!'); }
someFunction(); // safe
```

However, it doesn't seem to work with *function declarations*: <sup>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QqrBj/3/)</sup>

```
function someFunction() { alert('boom!'); }
someFunction(); // boom!
```

Is this behavior intentional? What is the reasoning behind it? Is this documented anywhere? Or am I just making some kind of silly mistake?

---

By the way, I'm using Chromium 17 to test this. Strict mode doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug [(see Bug #115452)](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115452), which I also encountered when answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347733/stop-a-function-from-execute-with-chrome-extension/9348685#9348685).

### Compatibility check: [Test case](http://jsfiddle.net/sbLh9/)

- In Firefox 4+, it works fine.
- In Chrome 16, it works fine.
- In Chrome 17, it does not work.
- IE8- doesn't have `Object.defineProperty`, so it doesn't work
- In IE9, it does not work.
- In Safari 5, it does not work.

Comment: Well, that certainly explains it. I wonder how this bug managed to crop up in three different UAs.

Comment: @GGG The [original version of the standard](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=es3.1%3Aes3.1_proposal_working_draft&cache=cache&media=es3.1:tc39-2009-050.pdf) did not define this behaviour. It was corrected [later](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=es3.1%3Aes3.1_proposal_working_draft&cache=cache&media=resources:es5_errata_7-31-10.pdf) (10.5 5.e.)

Comment: FWIW, this is where the errata originated from: https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es5-discuss/2011-January/003882.html

Comment: @GGG The bug has been marked as [**fixed**](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115452#hc4), and will be added into Chrome next week.