# Hijacking a variable with a userscript for Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts, content-script

I'm trying to change the variable in a page using a userscript.
I know that in the source code there is a variable

```
var smilies = false;
```

In theory I should be able to change it like that:

```
unsafeWindow.smilies = true;
```

But it doesn't work. When I'm trying to alert or log the variable to the console without hijacking I get that it's undefined.

```
alert(unsafeWindow.smilies); // undefined !!!
```

**EDIT: I'm using Chrome if it changes anything...**

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html says:

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated
>   world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into,
>   but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.
>   It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript
>   executing on the page it is running on.

It's about Chrome Extensions but I guess it's the same story with Userscripts too?

Thank you, Rob W. So the working code for people who need it:

```
var scriptText = "smilies = true;";
var rwscript = document.createElement("script");
rwscript.type = "text/javascript";
rwscript.textContent = scriptText;
document.documentElement.appendChild(rwscript);
rwscript.parentNode.removeChild(rwscript);
```

Comment: `smilies` it's not a variable declared inside a function?

Comment: No, it's not inside the function.

Comment: For longer function, use a self-executing format `scriptText = '('+ fn +')();';` where `fn` is any (possibly long) function within the extension.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In [Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment) (Chrome extensions), there's a strict separation between the page's global `window` object, and the content script's global object.

- To inject the code, [a script tag has to be injected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/938089?building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script).
- Overwriting a variable is straightforward.
  Overwriting a variable, with the intention of preventing the variable from being overwritten requires the use of [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) <sup>[Example + notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9348685/938089?stop-a-function-from-execute-with-chrome-extension)</sup>.

The final Content script's code:

```
// This function is going to be stringified, and injected in the page
var code = function() {
    // window is identical to the page's window, since this script is injected
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'smilies', {
        value: true
    });
    // Or simply: window.smilies = true;
};
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = '(' + code + ')()';
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

Comment: Thank you for your extremely detailed answer!!! I already solved my problem from the link (I believe it was you, http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/121923) gave me.

Interestingly I didn't need to use Object.defineProperty to make it work, I wonder why... Edit: Okay, you also wrote about it. Thank you again!!!

Comment: @BadrHari `Object.defineProperty` is only necessary if you want to prevent the variable from being overwritten, [as shown in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9348685/938089?stop-a-function-from-execute-with-chrome-extension). Currently, when your script is executed before the page's `smiley` variable has been declared, the variable will be overwritten by the page. Using `Object.defineProperty` prevents this from happening.

Comment: @minseong It depends. If you want to set the variable before it exists, definitely use `"run_at": "document_start"`. If you want to overwrite the variable after it has already been defined, using `"document_end"` or `"document_idle"` might work.