# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'colors' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am trying to create a chrome extension that allows a user to add a new color to Desmos, a graphing calculator, when the extension button is clicked.

The two basic files:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
    file: "add_color.js"
  });
});
```

and

```
(function() {

  if (window.location.href === "https://www.desmos.com/calculator") {

    var name = prompt("What would you like the name of the new color to be?");
    var hex = prompt("What should the hex code of the new color be?");

    window.Calc.colors[name] = hex;

  };

})();
```

But when I try running it, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'colors' of undefined`. If I run it using the DevTools console it runs perfectly. Could someone explain why?

Comment: The window in your plugin isn't the same as the window on the page. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485992/hijacking-a-variable-with-a-userscript-for-chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a webpage's evaluated Javascript variables from a content script. Your extension script, content script and THE page's script are running in different contexts. Your content script has access to the page's DOM and not the execution context. Thus, you need your content script to directly inject code into the page's DOM via add script tags.

Summary.

- Extension script has access to the chrome tabs.
- Content script has access to the page DOM.
- Page script is executing in a different context than the other scripts.
- Content script must inject code via adding script tags.
- Injected code can access page's evaluated javascript variables.
- Injected code can communicate back to content script using `window.postMessage`
- Then content script can communicate back to extension script via `chrome` API.

It's not fun...