# Detecting alerts with a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there some way for a Chrome extension to detect an alert box which shows up immediately after an external website's page-load? I understand that once an alert box shows up, JavaScript execution is suspended.

A certain website throws a specific alert and I need to be able to listen for that. Ideally, I want to extract the text within the alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overwrite the native `alert()` function

```
var native_alert = alert;

alert = function(msg) {
    console.log('call to alert() - message: '+msg);
    native_alert(msg);    
}

alert('intercepted!');
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/jHTeK/2/

Comment: This indeed works if you control the execution environment of the web page. However, the following accepted answer elaborates on your point in the context of the specific question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095924/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-javascript-code-that-overrides-the-one-existing-in-a

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You only need to insert the script in the document.