# Unable to replace Alert in injected script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension for [this](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/) site. In my injected script(injected using   `chrome.tabs.executeScript`) which runs at "document_end" everything seems to be working fine but I want to remove site's "alert" prompts.

To do I've placed this code in the injected script but it does not work:

```
window.alert = function(msg){
    console.log("bypassed");
}
```

Also tried this from the injected script:

```
$('<script>window.alert = function (msg){}</' + 'script>').appendTo(document.body);
```

I've even tried this in the background page but this too doesn't:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                code: 'window.alert=function(msg){}' //while alert("hello") works
            });
```

What am I missing? I've written another extension for another site and this method does override the `alert` function.

UPDATE: I'm unable to call native functions in the downloaded web page from the injected script which will happen when called from content script. But my injected script is loaded using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`

Comment: when you inspect the page with the extension on, is your script successfully appended?

Comment: @NoamHacker Yes it is for sure.

Comment: have you tried the proxy pattern that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1729684/4926817) uses?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12096099/4926817) recommends to run at document_start, rather than document_end, "so that the overwrite takes place before any of the page's functions are loaded". I will write up a more detailed answer

Comment: Ways 1 and 3 won't work because you'll be overriding the alert of the isolated world, not of the original page.  I don't see why way 2 wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your issue is with your `manifest.json` file, where you have specified to `"run_at": "document_end"`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

> In the case of "document_start", the files are injected after any files from css, but before any other DOM is constructed or any other script is run.

but,

> In the case of "document_end", the files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded.

Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12096099/4926817), in the case of `document_end`, the overwrite cannot take place as the functions are already loaded, therefore you should have the javascript be injected at `document_start`.