# Detect audio element not added to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, audio, google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering how i can detect an 'audio' element that is not added to DOM before playing. The code that creates the element is:

```
var snd = new Audio("short.mp3");
snd.volume = 1;
snd.play();
```

The audio source may change.

Later i will inject some JS into the page using a chrome extension when the selected tab is audible. Then the code should run and do a console.log with the audio source.

How can i check stuff about this element that is never added to DOM?

PS: I can't change the code that plays the audio.

Comment: You can overwrite the audio constructor.

Comment: Can you please say more about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12096099/3591628

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Found this later: [This answer by PhilHoy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/296667/296706#answer-296713) does exactly what mine does without adding another function to the Audio prototype. Wasn't familiar enough with `apply` when I wrote this, but the idea is the same.

---

Elaborating on Daniel Herr's comment:

> You can overwrite the audio constructor

Looking around online for a bit, I couldn't find a better answer than this. You said, "...when the selected tab is audible. Then the code should run..." so I elected to overwrite the `play` method instead. Essentially, I'm just:

- Saving a reference to the original `play` method
- Replacing it with a function that logs
- Calling the saved reference & passing along any arguments
- Returning the result

```
Audio.prototype.overwrite_play = Audio.prototype.play

Audio.prototype.play = function() { 
  console.log(this.src)
  return this.overwrite_play(arguments); 
}
```

If you assigned `play` to an arbitrary variable, you would get the following error: `'play' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLMediaElement.`

So I elected to just add the method `overwrite_play` to the prototype of `Audio` itself. That gave me a `this` that referred to the particular `Audio` object anyway, so I could just use `this.src` directly. Only other catch is I'm pretty sure this only applies to audio sources created through `new Audio` & not embedded HTML audio elements.

There're probably much cleaner ways of dealing with this, but it seemed to work for one of my use-cases (adding a volume slider to specific tabs).