# How to remove or overwrite a function on a page using injected javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace, null, overwrite, inject

I want to delete a javascript function from a page using an injected javascript, which is running through a Google Chrome extension.

For the purposes of the question, let's call the exampl,e function I want to remove testtest. In this case, the function looks like this on the page:

```
var testtest() {
    somecode bla bla bla;
    somecode bla bla bla;
    somecode bla bla bla;
    return false;
}
```

Basically I want to remove or prevent the function testtest from ever running on the page.

I was trying the javascript replace method to do it, but it isn't working. If this isn't possible I'd like an alternative solution to achieve my end goal (prevent the function from running on the page).

I'm getting Hello World popup which means the script is running on the page, but the code is not being replaced.

Here are my tries using javascript replace method:

***TRY 1:***

```
alert("Hello World!");
window.location = loc.replace(testtest, "aaaaa");
```

Conclusion:
"Hello World" popup: SUCCESS
**Code Replaced: FAIL**

--

***TRY 2:***

```
alert("Hello World!");
loc.replace(testtest, "aaaaa");
```

Conclusion:
"Hello World" popup: SUCCESS
**Code Replaced: FAIL**

--

***TRY 3:***

```
alert("Hello World!");
testtest= "aaaaa";
```

Conclusion:
"Hello World" popup: SUCCESS
**Code Replaced: FAIL**

--

***TRY 4:***

```
alert("Hello World!");
var str="testtest";
var n=str.replace("testtest","aaaaa");
```

Conclusion:
"Hello World" popup: SUCCESS
**Code Replaced: FAIL**

---

Perhaps javascript replace method isn't the right way to go about achieving my end objective. I don't really care exactly how I do it, as long as I achieve my goal. Please help me find a solution.

**Update:** I tried these other three methods but they also failed.

***TRY 5:***

```
alert("Hello World!");
function pacifyGlobalFunction(testtest) {
Object.defineProperty(
    window,
    testtest,
    {
        value: function () {},
        configurable: true // permit future Object.defineProperty
    }
);
}
```

Conclusion:
"Hello World" popup: SUCCESS
**Code Replaced: FAIL**

--

***TRY 6:***

```
alert("Hello World!");
Object.defineProperty(window, 'testtest', {
    value: function(){/*This function cannot be overridden*/}
});
```

Conclusion:
"Hello World" popup: SUCCESS
**Code Replaced: FAIL**

--

***TRY 7:***

```
alert("Hello World!");
var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    window.testtest = null;
} + ')();';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

Conclusion:
"Hello World" popup: SUCCESS
**Code Replaced: FAIL**

---

So I still need a solution.

Comment: Potential Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347733/stop-a-function-from-execute-with-chrome-extension

Comment: Why are you trying to modify the _URL_ in your code, when you say you want to modify a _function_?

Comment: Paul you're right about not needing `loc = window.location.href;` no matter still none of the tries remove the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
function testtest() {}
```

Is similar to:

```
window.testtest = function () {};
```

So `testtest` is a property of the `window` object.

You can use `delete` to delete properties from objects. So:

```
delete window.testtest;
```

Should remove the function. The function will still be *called* though .. so you might want to just redefine it.

Comment: I need the function to *not* be called, so this isn't a usable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your mention of *Google Chrome* means that you should have `Object.defineProperty`; make a non-writable property for `window` to prevent it being set to something else

```
function pacifyGlobalFunction(functionName) {
    Object.defineProperty(
        window,
        functionName,
        {
            value: function () {},
            configurable: true // permit future Object.defineProperty
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried this verbatim but it doesn't do anything, script still runs. Hello World popup in the same file ran fine, so the script is running on the page, just the code isn't working.

Comment: @user2651403 can you make an actual testcase on jsfiddle or jsbin for us?

Comment: not really possible to demonstrate. Since we're talking about changing or removing a function on a remote url using a chrome extension.

Comment: What is the expected output of your fiddle if the function is removed? The only other function call I see is `alert`.. you want to remove `alert`?

Comment: no. i put alert to make sure it's running. You can't use jsfiddle to see anything because I want to remove a function on a remote domain. The only way to demo is to set up a whole site just to make a function and then make and install the extension and visit that domain and see if the function is removed.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ijiruv/1/edit .. but in Chrome, turns out that doing `function foo() {}` will overwrite property `window.foo` even if defined as non-writable... may be a webkit bug, so you'll have to re-define after it was defined, not before as I'd hoped using my solution. It should work anything defined using `=` though e.g. `foo = function () {};`

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. How about update the answer to working code since you admit your answer is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the function.
For example, your old one would look like

```
function testMe() { 
   alert("Hi"); 
}
```

just overwrite it by empty content like this

```
function testMe() {}
```

So, when calling `testMe();` on page no alerts is popped up :)